# CMake and correct add shared library

Tags: c++11, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm trying to add a shared library to my project using CMake. The library is [MsgPack](http://msgpack.org/) for C++11. I must be doing something wrong because none of the examples [here](https://github.com/Lichtso/netLink/wiki/MsgPack) compile. I get this error:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are
>   ‘MsgPack::Serializer’ and ‘std::unique_ptr’)
>   serializer << MsgPack__Factory(Array(std::move(arrayWith3Elements)));

My guess is that it has to do with my CMake syntax. The file system tree  where I keep the compiled library looks like this:

```
/home/I/direcytory/MsgPack/
├── include
│   ├── Container.h
│   ├── ContainerHeader.h
│   ├── Core.h
│   ├── Data.h
│   ├── Element.h
│   ├── Header.h
│   ├── MsgPack.h
│   ├── MsgPackSocket.h
│   ├── netLink.h
│   ├── Number.h
│   ├── Primitive.h
│   ├── Socket.h
│   ├── StreamManager.h
│   └── Utf8.h
├── libnetLink.a
└── libnetLink.so
```

In CMake I'm doing this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(MyProject)

add_library(libnetLink SHARED IMPORTED)

SET_PROPERTY(TARGET libnetLink PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/I/Direcytory/MsgPack/libnetLink.so)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories("/home/I/Direcytory/MsgPack/include")

target_link_libraries(MyProject libnetLink)
```

CMake doesn't report any errors, but my program won't compile.

It's worth noting, *the above method has worked fine for me with other libraries*. That's what has me confused.

Comment: Origin of your error is somewhere in the source or header file. `MsgPack` include file has been found (otherwise corresponded error would be generated), linking to the library has not been performed at this stage.

Comment: So short say this library have a bug. ? If Yes I don't understand why is appear in oficjal site ..

Comment: It is impossible to say anything without viewing exact error message(with file:line identifications) and you source file.

Comment: Ok I leave this problem, because Link library was added correct. Example code was just copyed to simply program, and after this not working. Thank You for advance. SUbject to close